# How can I handle mismatch between schema and model after transformation?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, .net-core, ml.net

Exploring ML.Net and I want to predict employee turnover. I have a dataset available, with a mix between numeric and string values.

This is all just purely exploration in my attempt in getting to know ML.net. So my approach was to, simply step by step explore the options, so I really would understand each and every step as good as possible.

1. Load the data
2. Prepare the dataset and do a categorical transform on the string features
3. Display the dataset after applying the transformations
4. Then split the dataset into a train and test dataset
5. Train the model with a classification algorithm
6. Evaluate against the test dataset
7. Output the feature weights of the model
8. Do some cool stuff with it

The model is as follows and based on the open source attrition dataset from IBM. https://www.kaggle.com/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset

The model:

```
public class Employee
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        //[ColumnName("Label")]
        public string Attrition { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(2)]
        public string BusinessTravel { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(3)]
        public int DailyRate { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(4)]
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(5)]
        public int DistanceFromHome { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(6)]
        public int Education { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(7)]
        public string EducationField { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(8)]
        public int EmployeeCount { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(9)]
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(10)]
        public int EnvironmentSatisfaction { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(11)]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(12)]
        public int HourlyRate { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(13)]
        public int JobInvolvement { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(14)]
        public int JobLevel { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(15)]
        public string JobRole { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(16)]
        public int JobSatisfaction { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(17)]
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(18)]
        public int MonthlyIncome { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(19)]
        public int MonthlyRate { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(20)]
        public int NumCompaniesWorked { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(21)]
        public string Over18 { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(22)]
        public string OverTime { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(23)]
        public int PercentSalaryHike { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(24)]
        public int PerformanceRating{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(25)]
        public int RelationshipSatisfaction{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(26)]
        public int StandardHours{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(27)]
        public int StockOptionLevel{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(28)]
        public int TotalWorkingYears{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(29)]
        public int TrainingTimesLastYear{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(30)]
        public int WorkLifeBalance{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(31)]
        public int YearsAtCompany{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(32)]
        public int YearsInCurrentRole{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(33)]
        public int YearsSinceLastPromotion{ get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(34)]
        public int YearsWithCurrManager { get; set; }
    }
```

The string properties are then transformed (as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/prepare-data-ml-net#work-with-categorical-data)

```
var categoricalEstimator = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Attrition")
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("BusinessTravel"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("EducationField"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Gender"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("JobRole"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("MaritalStatus"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Over18"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("OverTime"));
            ITransformer categoricalTransformer = categoricalEstimator.Fit(dataView);
            IDataView transformedData = categoricalTransformer.Transform(dataView);
```

Now I want to inspect what has changed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/inspect-intermediate-data-ml-net#convert-idataview-to-ienumerable). The challenge I have now is that after applying a transformation on the string properties, the schema has changed and now contains the expected vectors.

So the following is happening. The Employee model schema does not match the schema from the transformedData object anymore and tries to fit a Vector property into a String property and throws the following error **"Can't bind the IDataView column 'Attrition' of type 'Vector' to field or property 'Attrition' of type 'System.String'."**

```
  IEnumerable<Employee> employeeDataEnumerable =
                    mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<Employee>(transformedData, reuseRowObject: true);
```

The CreateEnumerable also has a SchemaDefinition argument, so my first guess was to extract the Schema from the transformedData, and supply that to the CreateEnumerable. However it expects a Microsoft.ML.DataViewSchema and the schema produced by the transform is a Microsoft.ML.Data.SchemaDefinition. So that didn't work either.

I hope someone can advice me on this. Should I do something different?

Full Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Turnover()
{
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

    var _appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var _dataPath = Path.Combine(_appPath, "Datasets", "WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv");

    // Load data from file
    IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<Employee>(_dataPath, hasHeader: true);

    // 0. Get the column name of input features.
    string[] featureColumnNames =
        dataView.Schema
            .Select(column => column.Name)
            .Where(columnName => columnName != "Label")
            .ToArray();

    // Define categorical transform estimator
    var categoricalEstimator = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Attrition")
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("BusinessTravel"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("EducationField"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Gender"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("JobRole"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("MaritalStatus"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Over18"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("OverTime"));
    ITransformer categoricalTransformer = categoricalEstimator.Fit(dataView);
    IDataView transformedData = categoricalTransformer.Transform(dataView);

    // Inspect (fails because Employee (35 cols) cannot be mapped to new schema (52 cols)
    IEnumerable<Employee> employeeDataEnumerable =
        mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<Employee>(transformedData, reuseRowObject: true, schemaDefinition : transformedData.Schema);

    // split the transformed dataset into training and a testing datasets
    DataOperationsCatalog.TrainTestData dataSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(transformedData, testFraction: 0.2);
    IDataView trainData = dataSplit.TrainSet;
    IDataView testData = dataSplit.TestSet;

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this recently and as a quick workaround, I simply created a new class that matches the transformed data schema.  For example, you can create EmoloyeeTransformed class with the correct properties (i.e. vector instead of string) and use that as follows:

```
CreateEnumerable<EmployeeTransformed>
```

This isnt optimal if you are going to create various transformed schemas, but it works.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that initially but then thought "there should be a more easier way without duplicating my entire model twice". Also considering I am just touching the basics I was expecting alot of people to deal with the same issue.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you made EmployeeTransformed?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes you can also call transformedData.Preview() and look at the data and the resulting Schema.